# Does div.menu ul li a:visited inherits div.menu ul li a?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing some CSS EDSL and I can't understand the relation here

```
div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited {
```

It's part of default Microsoft ASP.NET WebForms template and I'm not sure if this is anyhow sane or not.

Because if this is sane then I am doing everything wrong.

what can I see now is

```
div.menu ul li a {
```

Will make the same effect because just `a` must affect all the other selectors.

And I can't see the reason why the authors do add `div.menu ul li a:visited` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the same property set to more than one property, use the comma. So:

```
 div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited {
    color: #ccc;
 }
```

will set the color for normal links and visited links. By default the browsers have their own color:

- standard link - `#0000FF` //blue
- visited link - `#800080` //purple
- active link - `#FF0000` //red

that was a standard but heavily differs per browser now.

Comment: I see, so I need to care browser defaults when write CSS. How can I know all the browser defaults? Like I want some "template" where I can override them all.

Comment: @ℋeatђer: If you want override them all, you should use some reset.css, this is the most [popular and basic reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), override some links color as you want and that's all

Comment: but look in this example http://chrisdone.com/x-normal.html -> http://chrisdone.com/x.html just a by itself overrides :visited , so why?

Comment: @ℋeatђer because the blue is just default by the browser, any CSS you write will automatically over write their default styles. So by doing `a { color: green }` you made all types of link (`:visited` etc) green, unless you further overwrite them with more specific rules like `a:visited { color: orange; }`

Comment: @Andy is right, another thing that you should know is that if you set a more specific value as `.foo a`, then its only override it's childs default value, while it's parent remain with the same color in case you don't do `a{color: #xxx}`, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/gmWBe/

Comment: then li a selector is not the same as li a:link ?

Comment: @ℋeatђer `:link` targets `a`elements that have a href set(meaning it is a link). `a` alone means anything inside that element regardless of whether it is actually a link. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/StJYK/1/

Comment: that's the way I were thinking about it before second comment here :P

Comment: @ℋeatђer Then you were right :) there is a difference between them, though it is very rare to have an `a` tag that isn't a link, so most people just use `a` to act as `a:link`

Comment: I accept this answer because of mistake about a:link and a made me to understand why designers find this more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In normal words:

> This style will be applied to every `a`, that is inside a `li`, that is inside a `ul` that is inside a `div` with a class `menu` **and** to every `:visited` `a`
>   that is inside a `li`, that is inside a `ul` that is inside a `div` with a class `menu`.

In other words: The properties from the anchor link when visited (or not) will be the same (for that `.menu`).

Also check out the [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more examples.

Comment: so if I write `div.menu ul li a` will it override defualt `:visited` for `div.menu ul li a` too?

Comment: When no `:visited` is specified, the `:visited` links will act the same as the specified `a` . See the difference between [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B55ey/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B55ey/).

Comment: so what the point of `div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited` then? why not just `div.menu ul li a` ?

Comment: In that case, there isn't a real difference (other than readability). Make sure you remember the first part (`div.menu ul li a`) will also target the other states (`:hover` & `:active`).

Comment: I'm asking exactly about this case. And I can't see even readability aspect here because it's confusing me, making me think that `div.menu ul li a:visited` for some reason could not being inherited from `a`.

Comment: What can I say even your "In normal words" is a mess. It's not normal anyhow. it's alike saying that every animal on the planet is creature and a cat, which is actually animal too is ALSO CREATURE.

Answer (score 0):

That means, the properties for anchor link and the anchor visited both are same.

Comment: I understand how to read it but doesn't `x:stuff` inherit all the `x` settings by default?

Comment: There are four instances ( link, hover, active and visited )hope you know this, by defining "a" only, it's only applied the property as a:link state.

Comment: In this case, `a` means the deprecated `a:link` so it doesn't affect the `a:visited`.

Comment: Yea and one thing more, I wanted to say, if you have only one property in :instance(except :link), then the parent properties (from "a") will also applied in the :other instances. By dening in "a" you can use it as a parent node..

Comment: @SudipPal but check this example: http://chrisdone.com/x.html just a overrides :visited here.

Comment: Try this..<style>a { font-size:20px;color: green }a:link { color: red }</style>

Comment: if I set a:link then a:visited is different but you said `by defining "a" only, it's only applied the property as a:link state` then it's not correct?